# Java class mapping for WordPress JSON - How to Get Categories / Tags

Tags: java, json, wordpress, jackson

I am using JackSON Library to Parse Wordpress JSON to a Java Class. The JSON can be seen at the following link:
https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/www.gjtutorial.com/posts?number=10&category=job-recruitment&pretty=1

I have been able to get the array of Posts with some of its nodes. However I can't understand how to get the list of Categories and Tags for each post.

My current Object Classes are:

```
public class WpJson {
public int found;
public List<Post> posts;

}


public class Post {
public int ID;
public String date;
public String modified;
public String title;
public String URL;
public String content;
public String excerpt;
}
```

This is how Tags and Categories are Structured in JSON:

```
        "tags": {
            "Medical Officers": {
                "ID": 272,
                "name": "Medical Officers",
                "slug": "medical-officers",
                "description": "",
                "post_count": 11,
                "meta": {
                    "links": {
                        "self": "https:\/\/public-api.wordpress.com\/rest\/v1.1\/sites\/63677311\/tags\/slug:medical-officers",
                        "help": "https:\/\/public-api.wordpress.com\/rest\/v1.1\/sites\/63677311\/tags\/slug:medical-officers\/help",
                        "site": "https:\/\/public-api.wordpress.com\/rest\/v1.1\/sites\/63677311"
                    }
                }
            },
            "Officers": {
                "ID": 415,
                "name": "Officers",
                "slug": "officers",
                "description": "",
                "post_count": 61,
                "meta": {
                    "links": {
                        "self": "https:\/\/public-api.wordpress.com\/rest\/v1.1\/sites\/63677311\/tags\/slug:officers",
                        "help": "https:\/\/public-api.wordpress.com\/rest\/v1.1\/sites\/63677311\/tags\/slug:officers\/help",
                        "site": "https:\/\/public-api.wordpress.com\/rest\/v1.1\/sites\/63677311"
                    }
                }
            },
            "Trainee Engineers": {
                "ID": 600,
                "name": "Trainee Engineers",
                "slug": "trainee-engineers",
                "description": "",
                "post_count": 6,
                "meta": {
                    "links": {
                        "self": "https:\/\/public-api.wordpress.com\/rest\/v1.1\/sites\/63677311\/tags\/slug:trainee-engineers",
                        "help": "https:\/\/public-api.wordpress.com\/rest\/v1.1\/sites\/63677311\/tags\/slug:trainee-engineers\/help",
                        "site": "https:\/\/public-api.wordpress.com\/rest\/v1.1\/sites\/63677311"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "categories": {
            "Jobs and Recruitment": {
                "ID": 67,
                "name": "Jobs and Recruitment",
                "slug": "job-recruitment",
                "description": "Employment, Recruitment, Job, Walk In, Interview, Entrance notification for Banks, Staff Selection Commission, SSC, Railway Recruitment Board, RRB, Public Service Commission, UPSC, Universities etc.",
                "post_count": 1030,
                "meta": {
                    "links": {
                        "self": "https:\/\/public-api.wordpress.com\/rest\/v1.1\/sites\/63677311\/categories\/slug:job-recruitment",
                        "help": "https:\/\/public-api.wordpress.com\/rest\/v1.1\/sites\/63677311\/categories\/slug:job-recruitment\/help",
                        "site": "https:\/\/public-api.wordpress.com\/rest\/v1.1\/sites\/63677311"
                    }
                },
                "parent": 0
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment but looking at the Post class. I do not see categories or tags in it. For example can you get author ?? 
Here is a example.
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-objectmapper.html

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
public class Post {
public int ID;
public String date;
public String modified;
public String title;
public String URL;
public String content;
public String excerpt;
public List<Tags> tags;
public List<Categories> categories;
}


public class Tag extends BasicField{}
public class Categorie extends BasicField{}
```

create BasicField class as fields are common between Tag and Categorie